# UK - Property Deeds

Tags: property

I am having a discussion with a neighbour over his suppose vehicular access to a shared lane. He says in his deeds he has access, but his deeds were destroyed in fire he says.

Now, are a copy of his deeds held by the land registry?

If so can I get a copy?

Will this be a full copy, or just a Title Register and Title Plan?

Or will a Title Register tell me what information I am after?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can get a copy of the land registry records [here](https://www.gov.uk/search-property-information-land-registry) for £3. They record all covenants, easements etc, so they should have the info you want, although the requirement to register property only applies to mortgages and transfers (sales etc) since 1990. If the property hasn't been mortgaged or transferred since then you may be out of luck.

You can also request [copies of deeds](https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-property-and-land), which go further back. That is more expensive; £7 per document.